# Append data from local DB2 table to remote SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I've been working on only this all day, and I'm still stumped.  I'm trying to append/insert data from a local (AS400/i5) DB2 table to a remote SQL Server 2005 table, as part of a program running on the i5.  My primary angle of attack has been using Java/JDBC to access the MSSQL table, but no luck so far.  It seems like this should be easy, but finding helpful information has been surprisingly difficult.  How can I make two separate connections interact programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I learn accessing SQL Server from RPG from Scott Klement-. http://www.scottklement.com/jdbc/

Hope this solve your problems - so far works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IBM i 7.1 with Technology Refresh 4 [TR4] then you have the ability to use 3-part naming under standard naming rules, which means rdbname.schema.table (or view). This enables a single SQL statement to reference data on two different systems.

The SQL-Server database will need to be added as an IBM i relational database directory entry (`ADDRDBDIRE`).  Read [this article](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/5a3856efecb7f19f8625672b006cee76)  for details.  For sake of discussion,  let's say you call the entry 'msdb'.

You should then be able to copy from SQL Server like this:

```
INSERT INTO localdb2table (columnlist)
    SELECT columnlist 
        FROM msdb.schema.sometable
```

(Caveat: I am not on TR4 yet, so I am unable to test this answer. )

Comment: True about i 7.1 TR4; but if you follow [**the article**](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/5a3856efecb7f19f8625672b006cee76) link all the way for SQL Server info, you'll reach "Typical Suggested Retail Price*: User license: USD $759.00 or Processor Value Unit (PVU) license: USD $75,900.00". Microsoft doesn't provide an open connection other through the JDBC Type 4 driver.

Comment: I have not used this, but it appears that [Microsoft says they support DRDA connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130703(v=bts.80).aspx) to SQL Server via Microsoft Service for DRDA as part of their Host Integration Services.

Comment: I took a few minutes (to try) to figure the cost of licensing it on the Microsoft side, but quickly ran into too many alternatives to calculate. Looks as if installs on a simple single-core system is approx = 4 user licenses of the IBM product. (Or not, hard to be sure.) It's still not clear why MS just doesn't go full on to simply support DRDA and be done with it, especially since they were part of the group that created it (before they chose to drop out and go with their own subset). My comment should've stated more clearly "MS doesn't provide (without paying extra)...".